# How many ways to fill a 10x10 grid under constrains

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways I can fill exactly 20 positions of a $10\times10$ grid with numbers in the set $S=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ under the following restrictions:

1. Each column must contain exactly 2 numbers (may or may not be same).
2. All numbers in each row must be different from each other except $0$ (i.e more than one $0$ may appear in a row).

Any hints to solve this problem is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify condition 1?  The condition "exactly 2 numbers" seems to contradict "may or may not be the same".

Comment: @Tad, For instance, if 1st row, 1st column position contains the number 3, then exactly one position left in the 1st column which must be filled with any number from the set $S$ including 3. So, the 1st column has two numbers and they are may or may not be the same.